# Why do some WPF binding fail against IronRuby properties?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, ironruby

So, lets say I have two *nearly* identical classes in C# and Ruby:

**C#**

```
public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        ImageLocation = "http://www.ironruby.net/@api/deki/site/logo.png";
    }

    public string ImageLocation { get; set; }
}
```

**Ruby**

```
class Test
    attr_accessor :ImageLocation

    def initialize
      @ImageLocation = "http://www.ironruby.net/@api/deki/site/logo.png"
    end
end
```

When I bind to the "ImageLocation" property in C#, all three controls bind properly.  When I bind to the same property with the IronRuby object, it works for `TextBlock`, but fails for `TextBox` and `Image`.  Here is my XAML:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageLocation}" Width="50" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ImageLocation}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding ImageLocation}" />
```

**Why does the binding work properly for one control, but not the others?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IronRuby types have a few problems with WPF binding... let's say that it's not perfect yet :)

To solve your problem, I recommend you to use CLR classes and types. For example, to make your sample code work just convert this line:

```
@ImageLocation = "http://www.ironruby.net/@api/deki/site/logo.png"
```

To this:

```
@ImageLocation = "http://www.ironruby.net/@api/deki/site/logo.png".to_clr_string
```

Comment: Thanks, Shay.  This is unfortunate :(  Calling that everywhere throughout the Ruby space will be cumbersome.  Is this a problem with the IronRuby interop?  Or is it a problem with the WPF databinding system?

I suppose there are two ways to make this more automated... create a decorator for all classes that are passed up to the View, or create a converter that the view uses that does this for you.

Comment: Its interesting, actually.  Really quickly, I added a ValueConverter that calls `(value as dynamic).to_clr_string();`.  It said that it failed to find the method :(  I want to avoid calling `to_clr_string` all over my beautiful Ruby code :)

Comment: So, I was just being dumb.  I created a value converter called ToStringConverter that simply returns `value != null ? value.ToString() : null;` and I plug it into my XAML.  All is good.  Thanks, Shay!

Comment: Cool! glad I could help you get to the solution!

Answer (score 1):

<del>Ivan Porto Carrero's book [IronRuby in Action](http://manning.com/carrero/) provides the solution to your problem. See [databinding.rb](http://github.com/casualjim/ironrubyinaction/blob/master/Chapter%204/databinding/listing4.5.rb) from the book's source code.</del>

This definitely doesn't solve the problem you're having, and I've repro'd it myself.

*Update:* Shay's answer worked for me, too.

Comment: I'm not clear to what the 'solution' is.  I see that he is solving the `PropertyNotify` problem... but I don't see how he solves the binding problem I am having.  I fully expect that all three controls in my XAML should be populated on start-up... without a change notification.  Unfortunately, this is not happening.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that. I am trying to determine whether you may have discovered a name-mangling bug in IronRuby.

Comment: @Brian: Sorry for answering the wrong question. I'll try to attach a test converter and see what, if anything, _is_ binding.